# Swift equivalent to category on NSUserDefaults with stored constants

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am accustomed to adding a category to `NSUserDefaults` to help manage the user settings without exposing the string keys used to store them. The idea was to hide the key names as an internal implementation detail of `NSUserDefaults` and only expose methods such as `setFavoriteColor`.

```
@implementation NSUserDefaults (AppDefaults)

static NSString * const kFavoriteColorKey = @"Favorite Color";

- (NSString *)favoriteColor
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kFavoriteColorKey];
}

- (void)setFavoriteColor:(NSString *)colorName
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorName ForKey:kFavoriteColorKey]
}
```

Usage:

```
NSLog("Favorite color is %@", [[NSUserDefaults sharedDefaults] favoriteColor]);
```

This also allows multiple unrelated classes to access and set `favoriteColor` without having to know any key names. I much preferred this to a single `Constants.h` file.

Attempting to use the same pattern in Swift, I am immediately foiled by the inability to declare new constants in extensions. Unless I'm missing something, I can't store the key name in the extension.

Can anyone suggest an approach that might reproduce the benefits of my objective-C approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use computed properties with an external Struct for the constants.

```
struct UDKeys {
    static let favoriteColorKey = "favoriteColorKey";

}
extension NSUSerDefaults
{
 var favoriteColor:String
    {
        get
        {
            // return what you need
            return Defaults[UDKeys.favoriteColorKey].string;
        }
        set
        {
            Defaults[UDKeys.favoriteColorKey] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Bonus: NSUSerDefauts API is not really "swift-friendly".
There is an awesome library to deal with NSUserDefauts in swift: https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults

Comment: Duplicating the key name twice is error prone and not an ideal approach in my opinion. I would consider that one of the criteria for 'reproducing the benefits' of the objective-C implementation. Thanks for the link.

Comment: For that kind of thing I use to use a struct with static string inside.
(I don't want to pollute the global scope with a global String).
I have updated my answer.

Comment: For particular cases you can use enum instead of structs.
Swift Enums are really really powerful :)

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to use a private function for each string constant:

```
private func kFavoriteColorKey() -> String {
    return "Favorite Color"
}

public var favoriteColor : String {
    get {
        return objectForKey(kFavoriteColorKey()) as String
    }
    set {
        setObject(favoriteColor, forKey: kFavoriteColorKey())
    }
}
```

Anything better?